# Make HTML <td> similar to Zurbs responsive tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I want to have a table with fixed heights of `<tr>'s` and have very long `<td>'s` being "continued" similar to [Zurb Responsive Tables](http://www.zurb.com/playground/playground/responsive-tables/index.html) but for a normal web browser(not on a phone).

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
            <td><div>This is a div in a td with a longer text</div></td>
            <td><div>This is aaaaaaaaaaaalso a td with a looong word</div></td>
            <td>Normal sized td</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This new example shows exactly what my problem is: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emilhem/D4FUH/2/)

The date column has to be as small as it is.

Does anyone know how to do this (preferably without any javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you trying to do but have a look at `white-space:nowrap` and `table-layout: fixed`.

Your css could be like this

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;  
}    

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

For exmaple for fixed width of `<td>`s add `width: 30%` to style for `<td>`.

Comment: Actually I would like to have some of the td's being able to be a certain size.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTR8M/6/) link this will help you to get the table like  [Zurb Responsive Tables](http://www.zurb.com/playground/playground/responsive-tables/index.html). and i just made some changes only in css

```
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px;   
    border-color:none;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

for alternate row colors,you may use this

```
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "rgb(225,225,225)");
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

i hope this will help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but when you mean longer do you want to have it horizontally wide or just vertically? As the 2 answers above do not give you

```
  Width:75%;
```

Which would expand according to the text and not break down into a new line, which basically would make your webpage go just horizontally rather than breaking it down into a new line as the content gets inputted.

So, basically if you want to expand it widely as well, then just add

```
  Width: [amount of px you want or % of page]
```

On the .css or inside the

```
  <td width="75%">
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.